# GDB cross-compilation for arm

Tags: linux, compile, arm, cross-platform, gdb

I cross-compiling gdb on ubuntu 16.04 to debug an application running on arm.
The main tutorial I'm following is
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingCrossGDBandGDBserver

The cross-toolchain installed on my ubuntu is aarch64-himix100-linux, and I had checked the target name via:

```
aarch64-himix100-linux-gcc -v
```

and the result shows
`Target: aarch64-linux-gnu`

I downloaded gdb-7.10.1 sources and extracted them into a folder named "gdb-7.10.1". Then I made two folders, "build_gdb" and "build_gdbserver", alongside the "gdb-7.10.1", and started to build:

```
cd build_gdb
../gdb-7.10.1/configure --target=aarch64-linux-gnu
make
cd ..
cd build_gdbserver
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu
make
```

the last step, `make` of gdbserver, broke with the following information:

```
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c: In function ‘aarch64_fill_gregset’:
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:233:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct user_pt_regs’
     collect_register (regcache, AARCH64_X0_REGNO + i, &regset->regs[i]);
                                                              ^
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c: In function ‘aarch64_store_gregset’:
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:246:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘const struct user_pt_regs’
     supply_register (regcache, AARCH64_X0_REGNO + i, &regset->regs[i]);
                                                             ^
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c: In function ‘aarch64_fill_fpregset’:
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:259:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct user_fpsimd_state’
     collect_register (regcache, AARCH64_V0_REGNO + i, &regset->vregs[i]);
                                                              ^
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c: In function ‘aarch64_store_fpregset’:
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:271:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘const struct user_fpsimd_state’
     supply_register (regcache, AARCH64_V0_REGNO + i, &regset->vregs[i]);
                                                             ^
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c: In function ‘aarch64_linux_set_debug_regs’:
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:581:29: error: storage size of ‘regs’ isn’t known
   struct user_hwdebug_state regs;
                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:316:0,
                 from ../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-low.h:21,
                 from ../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:23:
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:592:35: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct user_hwdebug_state’
   iov.iov_len = (offsetof (struct user_hwdebug_state, dbg_regs[count - 1])
                                   ^
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:581:29: warning: unused variable ‘regs’ [-Wunused-variable]
   struct user_hwdebug_state regs;
                             ^
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c: In function ‘aarch64_arch_setup’:
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:1220:29: error: storage size of ‘dreg_state’ isn’t known
   struct user_hwdebug_state dreg_state;
                             ^
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:1220:29: warning: unused variable ‘dreg_state’ [-Wunused-variable]
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c: At top level:
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:1272:13: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct user_pt_regs’
     sizeof (struct user_pt_regs), GENERAL_REGS,
             ^
../gdb-7.10.1/gdb/gdbserver/linux-aarch64-low.c:1275:13: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct user_fpsimd_state’
     sizeof (struct user_fpsimd_state), FP_REGS,
             ^
Makefile:257: recipe for target 'linux-aarch64-low.o' failed
make: *** [linux-aarch64-low.o] Error 1
```

Is this error some problems with gdb source code? How to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
If you encounter this question, please follow the :
[gdb wiki](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingCrossGDBandGDBserver) I mentioned in my question.
And my additional note to the gdb wiki is:

The "--target" of gdb as well as the "--host" of gdbserver should not be the "Target" line in the result of

```
aarch64-himix100-linux-gcc -v
```

, i.e. aarch64-linux-gnu, but rather be the name of your cross-toolchain, which, in my case, is "aarch64-himix100-linux".